# I'm try setting Sublime Plugin ftpsync for upload sass after compile with grunt and be specify file .php and .html

Tags: upload, ftp, gruntjs, sublimetext3

How should settings ftpsync.settings

```
"host": "ftp.host.com",
"username": "user",  // or null for anonymous login
"password": "pass",
"path": "/my/host/path/",
"upload_on_save": true, // set *false* if you do not want to upload on save!
"port": 21,
"ignore": "/scss/|/backup/|/node_modules/|/.sass-cache/|/src/|/.*?\\.json|/.*?\\.js",
```

on this line

```
"ignore": "/scss/|/backup/|/node_modules/|/.sass-cache/|/src/|/.*?\\.json|/.*?\\.js",
```

how to write be specify .html

and after Grunt compile sass upload to my host

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What do you want to do - add `.html` files to the `"ignore"` list?